# Which data type in c# is better suited for currency calculations?

Tags: c#, sql-server

And also the better counter part in sql server for mapping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Decimal and Decimal :)

- .Net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx
- SQL; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Comment: How does Decimal compare to Money (in MSSQL)?

Answer (score 3):

System.Decimal or 'decimal' is a 128-bit data type. Compared to floating-point types, the decimal type has a greater precision and a smaller range, which makes it suitable for financial and monetary calculations.

If you want a numeric real literal to be treated as decimal, use the suffix m or M:

```
decimal amount = 300.5m;
var dec = 300.5M; // same as above
```

The decimal is implemented in the CLR and is guaranteed to return the same result regardless of hardware.

JaredPar is right!